# Ionic2 Virtual Scroll huge dataset

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic2 (beta.11) Virtual-Scroll component to scroll big lists of data. For relatively small amounts (2000 items in array) it works fine. With big amounts of data (50.000 items in array) the scroll works fine in the browser, but get's stuck and works very buggy on the Ionic View Iphone testing.

The way the component works I have to load in all data initially. There is no way to load more data after a certain amount has been scrolled (as in infinite-scroll). As well the component docs say changing the dataset leads to a "reset" of the scroller.

How should this scenario be handled properly ? Anybody has experienced/solutions to handling huge amounts of list data in Ionic2 ?

Comment: The solution is don't have this situation. Your phone doesn't have infinity memory. Get only data you want to display. You can use sql lite to get only relevant data. Also ask yourself if the human mind can comprehend 50k of items in a list

Comment: Maybe try to integrate this Observable-based implementation of virtual scroll in Ionic2? https://github.com/dinony/od-virtualscroll

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? The proper way should be using virtual scroll and infinite scroll to get more data as the user scrolls down, but virtual scroll is buggy when data set is updated: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11788